# Call multiple API using akka HTTP

Tags: java, akka-http

I am new to AKKA , I am trying to  fire away the 3 requests, set a timeout to ~1 second for each to complete, aggregate the results. The 3 requests or multiple requests will be simple API call , GET, where the response from the API will be in JSON. So far the code I have

```
        final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, CompletionStage<OutgoingConnection>> connectionFlow =
            Http.get(system).outgoingConnection(toHost("https://example/api/ticker", 80));
    final CompletionStage<HttpResponse> responseFuture =
            Source.single(HttpRequest.create("/"))
                    .via(connectionFlow)
                    .runWith(Sink.<HttpResponse>head(), materializer).;
```

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are the 3 requests going to different hosts or the same host?

Comment: different hosts

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the `java` version of `akka` so the below example code may not be compile-able but it demonstrates the general idea...

Presumably you have functions for converting the response from previous API calls into requests for the next API:

```
public static HttpRequest convertAPI1Response(HttpResponse httpResponse) {

}

public static HttpRequest convertAPI2Response(HttpResponse httpResponse) {

}
```

These converters can then be placed inside `Flow` values:

```
final Flow<HttpResponse, HttpRequest, ...> convertAPI1Flow = 
  Flow.of(HttpResponse.class).map(convertAPI1Response)

final Flow<HttpResponse, HttpRequest, ...> convertAPI2Flow = 
  Flow.of(HttpResponse.class).map(convertAPI1Response)
```

These Flows can now be used in concert with the `outgoingConnection` flows that the question already references:

```
final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, CompletionStage<OutgoingConnection>> connection1Flow =
        Http.get(system).outgoingConnection(toHost("https://example/api/ticker", 80));

final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, CompletionStage<OutgoingConnection>> connection2Flow =
        Http.get(system).outgoingConnection(toHost("https://someOtherHost.com/api", 80));

final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, CompletionStage<OutgoingConnection>> connection3Flow =
        Http.get(system).outgoingConnection(toHost("https://someOtherOtherHost.com/api", 80));
```

And finally, all of the Flows can be connected together:

```
final CompletionStage<HttpResponse> responseFuture =
        Source.single(HttpRequest.create("/"))
              .via(connection1Flow)
              .via(convertAPI1Flow)
              .via(connection2Flow)
              .via(convertAPI2Flow)
              .via(connection3Flow)
              .runWith(Sink.<HttpResponse>head(), materializer).;
```

Comment: thank you very much,Sink.<HttpResponse>head() , gets the headers only i suppose , how to get the body of the response?

Comment: @RanveerBedaysee You are welcome.  The body is called `entity` and is represented by a stream also: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#httpentity